# How can I check in powershell if Get-ChildItem has failed?

Tags: powershell

In my powershell script I have the following line:

```
$DirectoryInfo = Get-ChildItem $PathLog | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }
```

to read some data from the path given in the variable `$PathLog`. But I realizes that even if the `Get-ChildItem` command failed (for example, the given path in `$PathLog` does not exist), and an error is written to the shell, the script continues.

How can I check if this `Get-ChildItem` was successfull? I want to use it to trigger an `if` clause as follows which stops the script at that moment:

```
if (???) {
    "There was an error"
    return
}
```

What to put into the brackets? How how to do it otherwise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "light-weight" alternative to `try/catch/finally` is the `$?` automatic variable. If the previous command failed, it'll have a value of `$false`:

```
Get-ChildItem F:\non\existing\path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if(-not $?)
{
    throw "Get-ChildItem failed"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Try/Catch` block to catch the error like @Beatcracker answered or if you really just care if it succeeeded or not, you can use `$?`.

> $?
>          Contains the execution status of the last operation. It contains
>          TRUE if the last operation succeeded and FALSE if it failed.

Source: [about_Automatic_Variables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx)

When using `$?` I usually hide the error from `Get-ChildItem` too, so I've added `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to do that in the sample.

```
$DirectoryInfo = Get-ChildItem c:\DoesntExist -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }
if($?) {
    "It worked!"
} else {
    "It failed! :-("
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Try/Catch` block and `-ErrorAction Stop`:

```
try {
  $DirectoryInfo = Get-ChildItem $PathLog -ErrorAction Stop | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }
} catch {
  Write-Error "There was an error"
  return
}
```

Comment: Does not work. Maybe a problem with the powershell version I am using?

Comment: It should work. His `Write-Error` will throw an error too, but it's content are different.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're parsing and whether you're interested in the exception, this might help:

`(Get-ChildItem Env:\MYENVKEY -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Value | %{ IF($null -eq $_) { $result="not found" } ELSE { $result=$_ } };`

It'll try and get the value and safely handle if it's found or not.